# How do i check if a node is a child of another node?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt

I want to get all "generateId" values of the text nodes which are a child of a specific node whose attribute "id" value is known. I can i test for this condition using XSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use an XPath 2.0 expression like this**:

**`//specificNode[@id=$knownValue]/text()/generate-id(.)`**

**You may also use keys** (`<xsl:key>` and the `key()` function) for more efficient selection of all specificNode-s that have an `id` attribute with a knownValue.

Comment: @Rachel: Was this the answer that you needed?